# Collaborative live editing using eclipse via FTP

Tags: eclipse, ftp, connection, collaborative

There is a plugin for eclipse called 'Saros' that gives you the opportunity to edit and share a project in real time with one or more of your friends and edit a file live with your friend (you can write on the same line).

But this can be done only on local server.

Today I tried to share a project from my Connections button but it didn't worked (I think 'Saros can't see through Connections button')

Anyways.There is another way to edit my project via FTP with eclipse or another program, live?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

May be try as an alternative aptana studio. http://www.aptana.org/products/studio3/download